# Unity Android Game is not Working Properly in Google Play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

Unity Game is working fine in Unity Editor, I even test it on Androidusing Unity remote 5. When I upload the game on Google Play Store, game is not working properly.
I have a gate on my runner game, gate has a collider and tag. On Google Play Store gate functions are not working! Google Play doesn't know this as an issue. So there wasn't PreLaunch Raport problem found.
Each testing is takes really much time because Google Play console update is takes much time.
What could be the reasons. Could it be code based?

I tested:
-Changing Unity version(from 2020.3.24f to 2021.3.8f).
-It reads collider and its tag.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the vibrating script which is some-how not working properly,So it probably giving error while working on android phone,. I couldn't saw any error because it is playing on android device.
(Interestingly now Ads are not shown! If I will find the reason I will update here.)